# SQLite transaction rollback different with in-memory database

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, transactions, in-memory-database

I have a C# application unit test that behaves differently when using a file-based SQLite database from an in-memory database.

When I run this code using an in-memory database within a unit test I get 1 record remaining after the rollback. Switch to a file-based database and I get 0 records. I would always expect the entire transaction to get rolled back and for zero records to exist in the database. Does anyone understand what could be different?

```
using System;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace DemoTransaction
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string conString1 = @"Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;foreign keys=true;";
            string conString2 = @"Data Source=C:\my_database.sqlite;Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;foreign keys=true;";

            using (SQLiteConnection dbCon = new SQLiteConnection(conString1))
            {
                dbCon.Open();

                using (SQLiteCommand dbCom = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE myTable (col1 INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)", dbCon))
                {
                    dbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                using (SQLiteCommand dbCom = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE myChild (col1 INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, col2 INT NOT NULL REFERENCES myTable(col1))", dbCon))
                {
                    dbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                SQLiteTransaction dbTrans = dbCon.BeginTransaction();

                try
                {
                    using (SQLiteCommand dbCom = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO myTable (col1) VALUES (1)", dbTrans.Connection, dbTrans))
                    {
                        // Successful query
                        dbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    using (SQLiteCommand dbCom = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO myChild (col1, col2) VALUES (1, NULL)", dbTrans.Connection, dbTrans))
                    {
                        // Intentionally bad query
                        dbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    dbTrans.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    using (SQLiteCommand dbCom = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM myTable", dbCon))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Records before rollback: {0}", dbCom.ExecuteScalar()));
                    }

                    dbTrans.Rollback();

                    using (SQLiteCommand dbCom = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM myTable", dbCon))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Records after rollback: {0}", dbCom.ExecuteScalar()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you completely sure that your in-memory tables are empty at the beginning of the test?

Comment: Yes, in the real unit test I have added a check to ensure DB is empty beforehand. I have also inspected the lingering record and it is the one inserted by the first query.